# Position of li elements in a 2 column list

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a 2 column list so that it orders to orders the element left-to-right, top-to-bottom. I have the following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <p>Title 1</p>
        <p>DD/MM/YY</p>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Title 2</p>
        <p>DD/MM/YY</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Title 3</p>
        <p>DD/MM/YY</p>
        <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>Title 4</p>
        <p>DD/MM/YY</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and CSS

```
ul {
  width: 300px;
}    

li {
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 47%;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  float: left;
}
```

The problem is "Title 3" is underneath "Title 2" whereas I would like it underneath "Title 1". The problem is because the height of Title 1 element pushes it to the right. The text is variable so I don't want to set a specific height.

I have created a JSFiddle to illustrate https://jsfiddle.net/wwzrbhno/

Comment: Tip: `display:table`, `display:table-cell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top` instead of the float.

```
ul {
  width: 300px;
}    

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 47%;
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

See this fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wwzrbhno/4/

Comment: This is the good solution. Please, stop to use floats to position elements. Floats are only for floating. It destroys the document flow. We aren't in the IE6 era, we can use inline-block, flexbox, and all good properties for this purposes.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I still float elements all the time. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: maybe your code is full of clearfixes. You can update your knowledge trying to design a web only using floats to floating elements.

Comment: Agree with Marcos float is not for positioning. and is a misused and misunderstood rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
ul { 
    width:300px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

and this will probably allow you to do away with the CSS for the `li`.

This is a `CSS3` feature however so limited browser support.